# How do I load a WKWebView before it appears in the view

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a `UITableViewController` with a `WKWebView` element in each cell. The `WKWebView` displays an iframe.

I've noticed that the `WKWebView` won't load the webpage until after the cell becomes visible. I want the content to load before it appears in the view frame. How can I accomplish this?

I'm loading the webView in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function, code snippet below. Appreciate the help!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "LinkTableViewCell"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? LinkTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of LinkTableViewCell")
    }

    cell.webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://streamable.com/s/7xixu/uiusrc")!))

    return cell
}
```

Comment: "I have a UITableViewController with a WKWebView element in each cell."  It doesn't sound like a good plot.

Comment: "I want the content to load before it appears in the view frame. How can I accomplish this?" The problem is that loading takes time. You can't get around that. You could use _prefetching_ to help with this, though.

Comment: Thanks @matt, I had actually previously tried prefetching, unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out how to use prefetching to load a bunch of WKWebViews...

Comment: I think you should use a placeholder image/thumbnail in each cell and when user interacts with that cell then you should do the actual loading. Loading the whole web doesn't look a good idea to me.